# Securing Master Password for Encryption in Android

Tags: android, encryption

I am using a common encryption library for android as given in this link: http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

How do I encrypt the "Master Password", currently I am hard-coding my "Master Password" in the code. I am afraid anyone could reverse engineer my code and find the "Master Password". By this, they can find the secured strings.

Please let me know if there is any standard workaround.

Comment: The 'snippet' you are using is broken and may not work on all Android versions, in particular the key generation part. Do use a key derivation function to derive the key from a password.

Comment: What I wrote less than an hour ago: "Those are terrible examples, they do not even specify the full algorithm (and probably defaults to ECB, not what you want for files). Furthermore, it uses the platform encoding instead of a specified encoding for the String (.getBytes()). setSeed() DOES NOT generate the same key each time, it adds the seed bytes to the random pool. To top it off, they use lingua far from the standard lingua, so you cannot look anything up ("clear" instead of "plain")."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should NOT hard code a password, master or not, unless a secure container of some sort is provided by the system.

You have to either request the master password from the user each time your application executes OR you can temporarily cache the password in the memory.

You can make the application clear the password from the memory after the application is idle for a pre-defined time.

Also, use a key derivation function like `PBKDF2` to derive a cryptographically secure key from a plain text password.

Comment: Is there a workaround to avoid the users from typing their Master password every time? How does Twitter app or Facebook or Gmail work with OAUTH?

Comment: There is no workaround I suppose. The password/key SHOULD be there to decrypt. If you don't want the user to enter it every time I am afraid you WILL need to store it somewhere. About Twitter/GMail, I am not entirely sure but AFAIK, they give a token of some sort to a 3rd party application that the application can use to access a user's data. The token does not contain the user's password. The only way to get the token is by asking the user to authorize the application which ultimately requires the user to login to Gmail/Twitter which obviously needs the password.